# SQL. Creating cumulative columns, past 7 days, past 30 days in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a table with a cumulative sum of sales, and another next to this column for the cumulative sales in the past week, then past month.

I'm using the regularly suggested cumulative script:

```
,SUM([SALES]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DATE]) [CS]
```

I'm messing around with this cumulative script to get the previous 6 rows:

```
,SUM([SALES]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DATE] rows between 6 preceding and current row) [C7]
```

The first works fine, however the second only gives the previous 6 rows. This would be fine if there was only one transaction per day per ID, but there are several.

Is there a way to change the "6 preceding and current row" to "6 preceding and current day"?

I'm trying to reach a result that looks like this:

CS = Cumulative sales

| ID | DATE | SALES | CS | CS7 | CS30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18273 | 01/06/2022 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 12 |
| 18273 | 02/06/2022 | 10 | 22 | 22 | 22 |
| 18273 | 03/06/2022 | 14 | 36 | 36 | 36 |
| 18273 | 03/06/2022 | 2 | 38 | 38 | 38 |
| 18273 | 03/06/2022 | 4 | 42 | 42 | 42 |
| 18273 | 03/06/2022 | 1 | 43 | 43 | 43 |
| 18273 | 14/06/2022 | 9 | 53 | 9 | 53 |
| 18273 | 15/06/2022 | 5 | 58 | 14 | 58 |
| 18273 | 14/06/2022 | 10 | 68 | 24 | 68 |

And the table goes on to include more ID's and values hence the partition by ID.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT
ID
,DATE
,SALES
,SUM([SALES]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DATE]) [CS]
,SUM([SALES]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DATE] rows between 6 preceding and current row) [CS_7]
FROM SALESTABLE
```

Hopefully I've explained it well enough. If not please let me know and I'll be happy to clarify.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks like you do not need PARTITION BY [ID]

Comment: Try `(partition by datepart(week,date))` and `(partition by year(date), month(date))`

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I still need to partition by ID as well as seeing the past 7 days for those ID's.

Comment: Sure, but you also need to introduce date functions to get the date ranges. Or you use an `outer apply` for the "sliding window" which may be better. I've only got a phone right now.

Comment: best I can do, doesn't agree with the cs7 or cs30 shown : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97d8074037b6af371a94f3bcff86cffe  the effect of partitioning may not be to your liking